# I need space beetween meta data by echo

Tags: php, echo

maybe somebody could help me with my problem.

I have this code :

```html
<?php if( $showPmeta ): ?>
    <span class="xoo-wsc-pmeta"><?php echo  $product_meta;  ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And my result is like:

> meta1meta2meta3

How I can have space between this meta data?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the function from where it get the string.

```
foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $bundleData = xoo_wsc_cart()->is_bundle_item( $cart_item );

if( $_product->get_type() === 'variation' ){
    if( $pnameVariation === "no" ){
        $product_name = $_product->get_title();
        $cart_item['data']->set_name( $_product->get_title() );
        }
    }

$product_meta       = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );

$cart_item_args = array(
    'product_meta'      => $product_meta,
);
```

Comment: What is `$product_meta`?

Comment: I presume `$product_meta` is an array, if so `implode(" ", $product_meta);` should work as you expected. But better to update your question and add what is `$product_meta`.

Comment: You've put extra spaces around the variable name inside your PHP code. That's not going to change anything about the output. You might use CSS to add padding or a margin onto the xoo-wsc-pmeta spans?

Answer (score 0):

Please show how you got `$product_meta`. I doubt that's an array since `echo()`'ng an array results in:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 1
Array
```

Not only will we get a `Notice`, we'll also only get `Array` instead of the array values concatenated.

If `$product_meta` is a simple array of strings, and you're calling a function to "convert" it to string, perhaps use `implode()` instead and use a space (" ") as the "glue", eg, `$product_meta = implode(' ', $product_meta)`.

Also, unless we're certain that `$product_meta` only contains alphanumeric characters, have it go through `htmlspecialchars()` on `echo()` to make sure it doesn't break your HTML, eg, `echo htmlspecialcars($product_meta)`.